# Grab two variables from structured character vector and create data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

Let's have a following vector:

```
vector <- c("0:00 0,6 0:00", "5:00 1,2 5:00","9:30 0,9 22:00","16:00 1,0","21:30 0,9")
```

We see that element contains:

hours,number (for instance "0,6"), hour2 (or blank)

It seems structured:
after ":" are always two digits ("00" or "30") then "" and number with decimal point (comma).

I want to create data frame and get data frame containing first hour and given number, like:

```
#Expected result:
df
$hours $value
#0:00   0.6
#5:00   1.2
#9:30   0.9
#16:00  1.0
#21:30  0.9
```

Comment: Avoid names like `vector`. If in doubt always try `?variable_name here` before choosing to use it as a variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
data.frame(hours = sapply(strsplit(vector, " "), function(x) x[1]),
value = sapply(strsplit(vector, " "), function(x) x[2]))

  hours value
1  0:00   0,6
2  5:00   1,2
3  9:30   0,9
4 16:00   1,0
5 21:30   0,9
```

It , first, splits the vector by `strsplit()`, then combines the first and second element in a `data.frame`.

If you also want to replace the comma with a decimal:

```
data.frame(hours = sapply(strsplit(vector, " "), function(x) x[1]),
value = sub(",", ".", sapply(strsplit(vector, " "), function(x) x[2])))

  hours value
1  0:00   0.6
2  5:00   1.2
3  9:30   0.9
4 16:00   1.0
5 21:30   0.9
```

It does the same as the code above, but it is also replacing comma in the second element by decimal using `sub()`.

Or:

```
df <- read.table(text = vector, sep = " ", dec = ",", as.is = TRUE, fill = TRUE)[, 1:2]
colnames(df) <- c("hours", "value")

  hours value
1  0:00   0.6
2  5:00   1.2
3  9:30   0.9
4 16:00   1.0
5 21:30   0.9
```

It converts the vector to a `data.frame`, with blank space used as separator and comma used as decimal, and then selects the first two columns.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
vec1<-sapply(strsplit(vector," "),"[")
df<-plyr::ldply(vec1,function(x) x[1:2])
names(df)<-c("hours","value")       
df$value<-gsub(",",".",df$value)
```

Result:

```
  hours value
1  0:00   0.6
2  5:00   1.2
3  9:30   0.9
4 16:00   1.0
5 21:30   0.9
```

Answer (score 1):

Another fun solution is to use `word` from `stringr` package, i.e.

```
library(stringr)
data.frame(hours = word(vector, 1), 
           values = as.numeric(sub(',', '.', word(vector, 2), fixed = TRUE)), 
           stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

which gives,

> ```
>   hours values
> 1  0:00    0.6
> 2  5:00    1.2
> 3  9:30    0.9
> 4 16:00    1.0
> 5 21:30    0.9
> ```